# Coffeescript external webrequest error

Tags: web-services, get, coffeescript, request, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to make a request to a webservice that is in my virtual machine but do not get the results. The url is perfect. Can someone help me?

```
$ ->
$.get "http://192.168.180.128:9000/listTasks", (data) ->
    $.each data, (i, task) ->
        $("#tasks").append "<option value=#{task.id}>#{task.description}</option>"
```

Answer (score 0):

try nesting the body of the document ready function inside the ready call

```
$ ->
  $.get "http://192.168.180.128:9000/listTasks", (data) ->
    $.each data, (i, task) ->
      $("#tasks").append "<option value=#{task.id}>#{task.description}</option>"
```

Comment: Dosen't work... apparently, the generated javascript can not make requests to external services. This same script works for an internal service.

Comment: not being able to make external requests doesn't sound like a compile problem if you can make internal requests, but its possible that you coffeescript is not getting recompiled when change the request host. Sounds like you have some problems outside the scope of this question to work out.